# How to find the limit $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(6x)}{8x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

How do you find the limit $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin 6x}{8x}$ ?

I know that I should try to manipulate this expression so it can have the form $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin6x}{6x}$ but I don't know how to.

Can you show me the way?

Comment: $\frac{\sin(6x)}{8x} = \frac{\sin(6x)}{6x}\cdot \frac{3}{4}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(6x)}{8x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(6x)}{6x}\frac{6}{8}=\frac{3}{4}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use Taylor series: $\sin(6x)=6x+O(x^{3})$ as $x \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: I haven't learnt Taylor series yet. Could you do it in full steps. Thank you

Comment: @JamesWarthington all this is is a more rigorous way of reminding you (*and the reason why*) that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\sin(6x)}{6x} = 1$, something which I trust you should already know.  Now, just get away from $8$ as the coefficient in the denominator to having $6$ as the coefficient in the denominator using all of the other hints provided.

Comment: @JamesWarthington: I misunderstood why you were having trouble. You can ignore my answer if you already know that $\sin(x)/x \rightarrow 1$ as $x\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Can you do this by expanding $sin(6x)$ into its Taylor series. I am opened to more advanced way of doing this excercise.

Comment: @JamesWarthington The taylor expansion of $\sin$ about zero (*or the /definition/ of $\sin$ in many cases if doing so from an analytical point of view*) is $\sin(z) = z - \frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\frac{z^7}{7!}+\cdots = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$.  Replacing $z$ by $6x$ that gives $\sin(6x) = 6x + O(x^3)$ where $O(x^3)$ is [big-oh notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and just means that everything else acts like or is smaller than $x^3$ and "*doesn't really matter*" in this case.

Comment: @JamesWarthington This all just leads to $\dfrac{\sin(6x)}{8x} \approx \frac{6x + O(x^3)}{8x} \approx \frac{6x}{8x}$ where we could just ignore the $O(x^3)$ since we are looking at the limit as $x$ approaches zero we have that all of those terms are so incredibly close to zero, so much more so than everything else, that they might as well have been exactly zero in this case.  Now, looking at $\frac{6x}{8x}$, you just cancel and are left with $\frac{3}{4}$

Comment: @JMoravitz, thank you very much for your detailed answer.